# Are there any stable complexes where an (N-unsubstituted) imine is bound eta^2 to a (late) transition metal?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, stability, organometallic-compounds

I've been looking for an example of a stable complex where a $\ce{C=N}$ is coordinated $\eta^2$ to a (late) transition metal, but could not find any. Do they exist at all?

For $\ce{C=C}$ there are countless examples, Zeiss' salt, $\ce{Ni(COD)_2}$, etc.

If no or only very few $\ce{C=N}$ analogs exist, what's the reason?

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/om050240t  Not exactly what you are looking for, but an example of $η^2$ imine on a rhodium complex. However their use of $η^2$ seems to refer to the entire connected imine moiety rather than through the double bond.